# Tracking LONG and SHORT profits separately in Pinescript Strategy tester?

Tags: pine-script

How do I input the trading strategy so that it accurately logs "enter long/exit long" and also "enter short / exit short" positions separately?

```
// LONG
    strategy.order("LONG", strategy.long, when = window() and buy)  // buy long when "within window of time" AND crossover
    strategy.order("SHORT", strategy.short, when = window() and sell)               // sell long when "within window of time" AND crossunder  

// SHORT
    strategy.order("SHORT", strategy.short, when = window() and sell and shouldTrade)  // buy long when "within window of time" AND crossover
    strategy.order("LONG",  strategy.long, when = window() and buy and shouldTrade)
```

[image]
But as you see in the image, it only shows "ENTER LONG / EXIT LONG" and it completely ignores the profits earned from "Enter SHORT / EXIT SHORT" which it doesnt even show.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Do you want to change the text that shows under the 'Type' column in the 'Strategy Tester' window? Or should I read your question more broadly, and do you mean to say that your short orders are not submitted by the strategy script?

Comment: The short orders are not actually being submitted correctly. That is what I mean't to say. It only seems to enter long and exit long with a short, but it should also show the `entry short`

Comment: Hard to test without seeing the full code. But can it be that the different orders compete with each other? Depending on your `shouldTrade` condition, two orders in these same direction can be submitted. I'm not sure how TradingView Pine deals with that, and if your pyramiding settings allow for that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly what you want is the `comment` attribute of `strategy.order` or `strategy.entry`. Whatever text you place there will show up in the order log allowing you to differentiate between different entries.

[Pine Script Reference - strategy.order](https://www.tradingview.com/study-script-reference/#fun_strategy%7Bdot%7Dorder)

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since your question is around. I have two suggestions:

1. Maybe it was something on the back-end which is just working fine by now? I've tested something similar and it just works
2. By the comments it looks like the short orders on the //LONG part are meant to close a position, not to close the long AND open short. Similarly, I understand the long orders on the //SHORT side are meant to close open short position, and not to close and revert to open positions. If this is correct, you may try a combination of `strategy.entry()` and `strategy.close()` instead of `stratagy.order()`.